# Tokenize with <br/> in xPath/xQuery

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, tokenize, line-breaks

I'm using this xpath expression `//*[@id='info_box']/p[contains(., 'Drafted')]` wich gives as output: http://pastebin.com/kRmCadiw (original output with original formatting)

What I want is to get all the text after the last `<br>`, so I used: `data(tokenize(//*[@id='info_box']/p[contains(., 'Drafted')], '\s*<br\s*/?>\s*')[last()])` but It still giving the full text in `<p>` (count(...)=1) even when trying with simple '
'... I don't understand what's missing!

The expected output is: `Drafted by the San Francisco 49ers in the 2nd round (33rd overall) of the 2005 NFL Draft.`

Answer (score 1):

Search for the last `<br/>` and then use a `following-sibling` axis step to find all elements after it. As you also need the text nodes not within an element, use node test `node()`. Because you only want the data, not the markup, add a call to `data()`.

```
/p/br[last()]/following-sibling::node()/data()
```

*(As you did not provide any example data, I'm starting at the intermediate output you posted to pastebin. Please add the first steps of your query in the beginning yourself.)*